# Set DateTime and Time in Symfony2 from String

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, time, symfony-2.1

In my entity, i have two fields, one type DateTime and other type Time.

I'm trying to do this:

```
$time = "05:45";
$date = "01-09-2015"

$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setDate(new \DateTime($date));
$entity->setTime($time);
```

In both case, Symfony told me that the code has problems with format.

I also tried:

```
->setDate(new Datetime($date));
->setDate(DateTime::createFromFormat($date, 'd-m-Y));
->setTime(strtotime($time));
```

Always with the same result.

If anybody could help me, i'll be thankful.

Thanks

---

UPDATED

Now, I tried

```
$date = strtotime($date);
$time = strtotime($time);
$entity->setDate(date("d-m-Y", $date));
$entity->setTime(date("H:i",$time));
```

And Symfony told me:

Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

```
in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/TimeType.php at line 53   -
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ($value !== null)
            ? $value->format($platform->getTimeFormatString()) : null;
    }
    /**
```

I also tried this:

```
$dateObject = new DateTime();
$date = $dateObject->format('d-m-Y');
$time = $dateObject->format('H:i');
$entity->setDate($date);
$entity->setTime($time);
```

And symfony told me:

```
Attempted to call method "format" on class "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime". On line "$date = $dateObject->format('Y-m-d');"
```

Thanks for the help

---

Updated - Resolve

Finally, yesterday a resolved the problem, using this:

```
$entity->new Entity();
$entity->setDate(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',$date));
$entity->setTime(\DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i',$time));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you copy-paste Symfony's error message, please?

Comment: I'm out. In three hours i'm going to be at home and i'll put the error code. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the post with the results of the changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Symfony doesn't know where to find `DateTime` class, so it is searching in the wrong (default) namespace. Use a leading `\`.

Moreover you inverted the `format` argument and the `time` argument in the `createFromFormat()` function.

So your code becomes:

```
$time = "05:45";
$date = "01-09-2015"

$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setDate(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date));
$entity->setTime(\DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time));
```

By the way, are you sure you really need to split Date and Time in your entity? It depends on your case but you could do this instead (only one object to manipulate):

```
$time = "05:45";
$date = "01-09-2015"

$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setDateTime(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $date.' '.$time));
```

Comment: Hi! Yes, i need to split Date and Time. I updated the post with the final result that i got last night. It's very similar than your andswer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php to be sure that your format fits.

Or check mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year)
Or check strtotime(time,now)
e.g. here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$dateObject = new DateTime();
$date = $dateObject->format('Y-m-d');
$time = $dateObject->format('H:i:s'); // or $time = $dateObject->format('H:i'); if you dont want to have the seconds

$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setDate($date);
$entity->setTime($time);
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, buy know Symfony throw this error:

Attempted to call method "format" on class "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime".

On line "$date = $dateObject->format('Y-m-d');"

Comment: Instead of $dateObject = new DateTime(); use:
$dateObject = new \DateTime(); // see the \ for the DateTime

Comment: Finally I resolved it with createFromFormat and it works perfect. Thanks!